# Java Null Pointer Exception with ListSelectionEvent

Tags: java, swing, awt, jlist

I'm going mad with this method which results in a runtime NullPointer exception when I remove a row in my database:

```
private void menuListValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {                                      
    int index = menuList.getSelectedIndex();
    int size = model.getSize();
    if (index >= 0) { 
        bDeleteMenu.setEnabled(true);
    } else { 
        bDeleteMenu.setEnabled(false);
        }
    Menu selectedMenu = (Menu)menuList.getSelectedValue();
    menuName.setText(selectedMenu.getMenuName());
}
```

The error is in this line:
menuName.setText(selectedMenu.getMenuName());

and occurs only when I remove an item.
This is the error:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException.
I guess this happens because when I remove the item in the Jlist the selection doesn't change automatically to the next one, or something like that.

And this is the method which I use to remove an item:

```
private void bDeleteMenuActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    Menu selectedMenu = (Menu)menuList.getSelectedValue();
    selectedMenu.getMenuName();
    int index = menuList.getSelectedIndex();
    DBConnection.deleteMenu(selectedMenu);
    int size = model.getSize();
    if (size == 0) { 
        bDeleteMenu.setEnabled(false);
    } else { 
        if (index == model.getSize()) {
            index--;
        }
        menuList.setSelectedIndex(index);
        menuList.ensureIndexIsVisible(index);
    }
    model.removeElement(selectedMenu);
    menuName.setText("");
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you confirmed if `getMenuName()` is not returning a `null` value?

Comment: Have you checked which of those is the `null` value? It could be `selectedMenu`,`menuName`,`selectedMenu.getMenuName()`, Maybe try printing the three of them out to give you a pointer in the right direction (instead of a null pointer hardy har)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrieving the name of the selected menu only makes sense in case where something is selected.

Replce

```
if (index >= 0) { 
    bDeleteMenu.setEnabled(true);
} else { 
    bDeleteMenu.setEnabled(false);
}
Menu selectedMenu = (Menu)menuList.getSelectedValue();
menuName.setText(selectedMenu.getMenuName());
```

with

```
if (index >= 0) { 
    bDeleteMenu.setEnabled(true);
    Menu selectedMenu = (Menu)menuList.getSelectedValue();
    menuName.setText(selectedMenu.getMenuName());
} else {
    bDeleteMenu.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works fine, thank you! But I don't understand why.

Comment: When nothing is selected, `index` has value -1 in it. So in that case, `selectedMenu` would be `null` since `menuList.getSelectedValue()` would return null. So you would get a nullpointerexception in the next line

Comment: Thanks a lot! But now I don't understand why in my previous version it worked fine, the difference is now I'm working with (menu) objects, previously I was working with the strings and this was the lines
String field = (String) menuList.getSelectedValue();        menuName.setText(field);
and were outsite the if block!

Comment: `selectedMenu.getMenuName()` is giving the nullpointerexception. In your previous code, selectedMenu was not dereferenced, you weren't getting any exception

Comment: Glad to know it helped. You may want to accept it if you feel it to be helpful so others know that your issue has been resolved. Good luck.